# Finding the number of sequences $(a_1, a_2, a_3, ..., a_n)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given that $a_i =0, 1$ for $1 \leq i \leq n,$ find the number of sequences $(a_1, a_2, a_3,..., a_n)$ such that $$a_1 \leq a_2 \geq a_3 \leq a_4 \cdots$$

---

I was thinking that I should somehow just arrange the $1$'s and $0$'s and be done with the problem, but I'm unsure if there's a problem with my logic here. Can someone confirm or deny my logic?

Comment: I don't understand what your logic is.  What result does it lead to?

Comment: @questionasker Your approach is not clear. I suggest writing down a recurrence for the answer.

Comment: Hint: Let $k\in\{0,1,\ldots\}$. Observe that if $a_{2k+1}=1$, then $a_{2k}=1$ and if $a_{2k}=0$, then $a_{2k+1}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern repeats at $a_3$.

Let $a_2 = 0$, then $a_1$ has to be $0$.

Let $a_2 = 1$ then $a_1$ is either $0$ or $1$.

Let $a_3 = 0$ then $a_2$ is $0$ or $1$.

Let $a_3 = 1$ then $a_2$ has to be $1$.

Until $a_1$, there are $2$ solutions.

Until $a_2$, there are $3$ solutions.

Until $a_3$, there are $3 + 2 = 5$ solutions.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Ah, so it's just the Fibonacci sequence?

Comment: Correct. But with shifted Index as it is not starting with 1,1....